# error while passing state and props

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react, unable to pass data from parent to child component. This is my parent component. I included my child component in the mapping. So it should be called each time by passing `user.login` which I need in child component to fetch github api for repos.

```
const users = this.props.userList.map((user) => (

    <div className="container">

        <div className="jumbotron container" key={user.login}>
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-sm-3">
                    <img src={user.avatar_url}
                        className="rounded-circle" alt="Cinque Terre" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <h3>  {user.login}</h3>
                    <p>    Profile URL : {user.html_url} </p>
                    <p>     Score : {user.score}   </p>
                    <p>    Type :  {user.type}</p>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row pull-right">
                <div className="col-12">
                    <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-lg"
                        data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample"
                        aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample"  value={user.login}
                        id="b1" onclick={this.callUser.bind(this)} >Details</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">                                  
           <UserRepo repoCall={this.props.user.login}/>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Child component**

```
class UserRepo extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { repoCall: [] }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    console.log('Repo-----------')
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall.login+'/repos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      user => {
        this.setState({
          repoCall :repoCall
        });
        console.log('here is repo' +  repoCall);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.repoCall.login` or `this.props.repoCall`?

You are getting repoCall as `this.props.user.login` I assume it returns username. So in your fetch you are using that does not exist: `repoCall.login`

Try that fetch as:

```
fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall+'/repos')
```

It seems your setState is not right. You are using `user` but trying to set the state with `repoCall`.

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.repoCall}/repos`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(repoCall => this.setState({repoCall}));
  }
```

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    console.log('--------------repo---')
    fetch(`https://api.github.com/users/${this.props.repoCall}/repos`)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(repoCall => this.setState({repoCall})
   //   console.log(repoCall)
    );
    console.log(repoCall)
    console.log('----rrr----------repo---')
  }

Comment: I am getting error as repoCall is not defined at console.log(repoCall)

Answer (score 0):

In parent:

```
<div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">                                  
       <UserRepo repoCall={user.login}/>
</div>
```

in child:

```
componentWillMount(){
    console.log('Repo-----------')
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall+'/repos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        user => {
            this.setState({
                repoCall :repoCall// not sure what is going on here mb user.repoCall?
            });
            console.log('here is repo' +  repoCall);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: at repoCall :user.repoCall I am getting repoCall not defined

Comment: I'm not sure what are you trying to do there, what exactly you expecting to comeback from fetch and what do you want to put in state?

Comment: In my child component i want to get followers, following, repository, lang

Comment: using login i.e username from parent , I am fetching github specific user info in my child component

Comment: what it looks like right now is that you have to go through your `user` json object and extract needed fields, push them into temp array and than call set state

Answer (score 0):

First of all you said `I included my child component in the mapping.`

Then use following.

```
<div className="collapse" id="collapseExample">                                  
  <UserRepo repoCall={user.login} />
</div>
```

Secondly to fetch `componentWillMount` is not your best bet instead use `componentDidMount` and param name to fetch should be `this.props.repoCall`

```
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Repo-----------')
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall+'/repos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        repoCall => {
            this.setState({
                repoCall
            });
            console.log('here is repo' +  this.state.repoCall);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="jumbotron container">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Data Label :{repoCall.followers}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Data Label </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }

Comment: Now I am trying to display followers . i am getting repoCall not defined at repoCall.followers

Comment: are you sure in parent mapping `user` does contains followers as well. can you post a bit of JSON.

Comment: in parent Im using https://api.github.com/search/users?q= for user search

Comment: in child im using dat login in   fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall+'/repos') to get followers, following , repo

Comment: followers are part of main `user` object not `user.login` so in that case in parent component pass following `<UserRepo repoCall={user} />` and then in your child access followers using `this.state.repoCall.followers`.

Comment: My parent comp fetch has different link which only gives login,html_url, few other urls

Comment: Im using dat login in my child to fetch with another link which gives all followers, following ,repo info

Comment: In that case this.state.repoCall.followers should work. Can you post code how and where you are accessing followers in child component.

Comment: componentDidMount() {
    console.log('--------------repo start---')
console.log( 'check='+ this.props.repoCall)

    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall+'/repos')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(
        repoCall => {
            this.setState({
                repoCall 
                // not sure what is going on here mb user.repoCall?
            });
            console.log('here is repo' +  this.state.repoCall);
        }
    );
      console.log('----rrr---------end---')
  }

Comment: render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div class="jumbotron container">
                <table class="table table-striped">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Data Label :{this.state.repoCall.followers}</td> 
                        </tr>
                        <tr >
                            <td>Data Label </td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

Answer (score 0):

1. Changed componentWillMount to componentDidMount
2. console.log added to setstate call back function
3. console.loged the return from the api call.

Try changing your child component like the below snippet and check console.

```
class UserRepo extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state ={  repoCall: []}

}

componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Repo-----------')
    fetch('https://api.github.com/users/'+this.props.repoCall.login+'/repos')
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
        repoCall=> {
            this.setState({repoCall :repoCall},()=>console.log('here is repo' +  this.state.repoCall));
        }
    );
}
```